# SDL Relative Position

Tags: c, sdl

I have a theoretical question about SDL' Surface cursor.
If I want to display surface_A on my screen I'll use a cursor created with `SDL_Rect cursor;` and I'll use it with `SDL_BlitSurface();`.
The cursor will contain a position relative to the top-left corner of my window.

But if I want to display surface_B inside surface_A, do I have to indicate a cursor relative the top-left corner of my window or the top-left corner of surface_A ?

Comment: Its probably not theoretical, but it's also certainly not easy to find in the documentation.  Have you poured through the _[wiki pages](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Rect)_?

Comment: @ryyker SDL's Wiki is not really helpful, I think I'll die if read it one more time XD

Comment: @CharlesLeroy wiki is surely easier to understand than this question. I've read it 3 times and I'm still not sure what question is. Blit takes two rects - source and destination - each relative to their surfaces.

Comment: @keltar, well I can't see in the rect wiki where is the info saying that the retcs are relative to their surfaces, can you make it as a response ?

Comment: Read through the tutorial I have linked below, and it's predecessor _[SDL Basics](http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-tutorial-basics)_.  This is a very good accompaniment to the wiki pages, and should help to clear up your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You may be making some wrong assumptions about the relative positions of your cursors.  There is a very good, and detailed set of tutorials at the linked location that may clear things up for you...

From *[HERE](http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-coordinates-and-blitting)*...

> Using the first tutorial as our base, we'll delve more into the world
>   of SDL surfaces. As I attempted to explain in the last lesson, SDL
>   Surfaces are basically images stored in memory. Imagine we have a
>   blank 320x240 pixel surface. Illustrating the SDL coordinate system,
>   we have something like this:

[image]

> This coordinate system is quite different than the normal one you are
>   familiar with. Notice how the Y coordinate increases going down, and
>   the X coordinate increases going right. Understanding the SDL
>   coordinate system is important in order to properly draw images on the
>   screen.

Some additional terms that may help clarify:

*[SDL Window](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow)* : You can think of this as physical pixels, or *your monitor*.
*[SDL Renderer](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Renderer)* : Controls the properties/settings of what is created in that window.

Comment: I'm learning SDL with 1.2 not 2.0, SDL_CreateWindow is only on 2.0 according to the exemple of the wiki

Comment: Its _[open source](https://www.libsdl.org/license.php)_.  Is there a reason you are choosing not to use the most current version?  But given you cannot, then I have not really answered your question, and you should de-select the accepted check so others will not be discouraged from seeing if they can help.

Comment: yeah the MOOC I'm following is based on SDL1.2 and C. The next one is C++ and Qt.